# Determine Events of a Hypothetical Sample Space

Tags: probability

This is a problem in S.Ghahramani's "Fundamentals of Probability with Stochastic Processes": At a busy international airport, arriving planes land on a first-come, first-served basis. Let $E=\text{there are at least five planes waiting to land,
}$ and $F=\text{there are at most three planes waiting to land}$. Can anyone please explain how $E^{c}=\text{the event that at most four planes are waiting to land}$ and $F^{c}=\text{the event that at least four planes are waiting to land}$? What is the sample space here which leads to this conclusion?

Comment: The random variable should be defined somewhere (I don't know if it is; I've never read that book), but it appears to be the number of planes waiting to land, which is a nonnegative integer. So "at least 5" includes all integers greater than or equal to 5. The opposite would be the nonnegative integers less than 5, i.e. "at most four".  Based on that explanation, can you explain the answer to your other question?

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.